# Will upgrading disrupt online backup software (Crashplan)?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, backup, crashplan

Has anyone had any experience upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04, and how this might affect online backup software processes? Specifically, I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.10 and using Crashplan v3. Crashplan backup engine runs constantly in the background to monitor files for changes and back up accordingly.

Will upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 affect any of the Crashplan backup process? Has anyone done this successfully? I'd like to upgrade to the latest and greatest Ubuntu release, but not at the risk of affecting the backup, or worse, having to start from scratch again and upload the entire library!

Answer (score 1):

Crashplan support recommends uninstalling the program first then reinstalling once you have upgraded you OS.

This can be done by running the uninstall script located in the Crashplan-install folder.

Once you have reinstalled you can adopt your previous backup for your upgraded system.

[Reference](http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/recipe/reinstall#overview)

Answer (score 0):

We're seeing that, with 11.04 and Crashplan V3, we always get the message "No files selected for backup", no matter what files are actually selected. Not a problem with prior version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm am successfully using CrashPlan on Ubuntu 11.04 (natty). You should have no problems with CrashPlan on 11.04 of itself. I had also used it on Ubuntu 10.10, but I performed a fresh install of 11.04. 
If your primary concern is having to re-upload all of your data, CrashPlan allows you to 'adopt' a previous computer. This means that e.g. a fresh install of 11.04 would be considered a new computer. When you start CrashPlan for the first time and log in, you can select a previous 'computer' (the one you had from 10.10) and effectively take it over, making the newly installed 11.04 replace it, saving yourself a lot of backup time.

http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/recipe/adopting_another_computer?redirect=1